# Copy paste data from <mat-table> <mat-header-cell>

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

want to copy paste data from Mat table. I was tried selecting data and right click for copy but it assumes as string format not in table.

[image: table Format]
want this format but got in

[image: string format]

this format

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<!-- Position Column -->
<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

trying to copy from mat table but got in string format

Comment: Could you please add your html code?

Comment: hey, I added the HTML code, sorry for the late replay!